# Semaphores in Java JVM processing and controlling of Thread

Tags: java

My question is regarding Semaphores.. Please can any one explain to me the concept behind Semaphores? I have understood the basic of it. but i am still not able to figure out **why semaphore class implements serializable**.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

```
public class Semaphore extends Object implements Serializable
```

Please try to answer my question in depth, using how JVM handles Multimple threads and how Semaphore controls it.

Answer (score 1):

use the links for semaphore with example.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/locking-with-semaphore-example.html

http://javapapers.com/core-java/semaphores-using-java/

Answer (score 0):

From a normal usage point of view, you don't want to serialize your semaphore. So in that sense, it is a bit stupid.

A lot of stupid choices have been taken for the sake of compliance.. and this is one of them.